# Increasing a value with a given interval in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a program where the user clicks a button and a value starts increasing at a given rate. For simplicity, let's say that it increases by 1 per second.

Every additional time the user presses the button, it will start to increase faster, say you press it two additional times and now it's increasing at 3 per second.

I feel like I need to use the setInterval method but I'm having trouble with the implementation and specifically how I would go about increasing the rate. Here's my HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="counter();">Counter</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Comment: You need to include the code you've tried. It doesn't matter that it doesn't work. If it worked, you wouldn't be here.

Comment: Just increase delta, not interval. If you want it, use `clearInterval`

Comment: Put the frequency in a global variable. When the user clicks the button, clear the old interval timer, increase the frequency variable, then start a new interval with the shorter timeout.

Comment: "increasing at 3 per second" — increase by Three every One second, or increase by One every Third-of-a-second? It makes a difference how you'd implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.
So basically the idea is set initial `step` to `0`.

Initiate loop which increases the volume by `step` number.

Each time button pressed you increase `step` number:

```js
var step = 0,
  count = 0,
  res = document.getElementById("count");

var timer = setInterval(loop, 1000);
loop();

function loop() {
  count += step;
  res.textContent = count;
}

function counter() {
  step++;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="counter();">Counter</button>
<button type="button" onclick="step=0;count=0">Reset</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Another approach is to decrease `setInterval` speed with each step:

```js
var count = 0,
  step = 0,
  res = document.getElementById("count");

var timer;
loop();

function loop() {
  res.textContent = count++;
}

function up() {
  step++;
  counter();
}

function down() {
  step--;
  if (step < 1)
    step = 1;

  counter();
}

function counter() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(loop, 1000 / step);
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  step = 0;
  count = 0;
  loop();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="up();">Up</button>
<button type="button" onclick="down();">Down</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your usecase. But based on your explanation
you can do what you want like this.

```js
const counterButton = document.querySelector('#counter');
const countDisplay = document.querySelector('#count');

delta = 0;
currentVal = 0;
interval = null;

const updateVal = () => {
  currentVal += delta;
      
  countDisplay.innerHTML = currentVal;
}

counterButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  delta += 1;

  if (!interval) {
    updateVal()
    
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      updateVal()
    }, 1000)  
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="counter">Counter</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

If you want to speed up interval, not the delta, this can help you.

This reduce the tick as button clicks, until the tick reaches to 10ms.

```js
var dlta = 0;
var sum = 0;
var interval;
let tick = 1000;

function onInterval() {
  sum += 1;
  $('#count').html(sum);
}

function counter() {
  dlta++;
  if (interval)
    clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(onInterval, tick);
  tick -= 1000 / (dlta + 5);
  if (tick < 0) tick = 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="counter();">Counter</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. Create a new interval every time you click on the button. Do not forget to clear the old interval.

- You can use a **linear increment** with a constant `DECREASE_RATE` for the interval time

```js
let time = 2000,
  interval = null,
  counter = 0;

const DECREASE_RATE = 100; // Modify it depends on your needs

function start() {
  if (time > DECREASE_RATE) {
  
    clearInterval(interval);  // Reset Interval
    
    // New interval
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById("count").innerText = counter;
      counter++;
    }, time);
    
    // Decrease time
    time -= DECREASE_RATE;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="start();">Counter</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

- Or you can use an **exponential increment**, every time you clicked it would go two times faster:

```js
let time = 2000,
  interval = null,
  counter = 0;


function start() {

  clearInterval(interval); // Reset Interval

  // New interval
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("count").innerText = counter;
    counter++;
  }, time);

  // Decrease time
  if (time >= 2)
    time -= time / 2;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="start();"> Counter</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```